# MVC IIS7 HttpContext.Current.Profile is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to set up my site to work with IIS7 MVC 3.

At first HttpContext.Current.User was null,

Then I removed and added models: Session, FormsAuthentication
in system.webServer Models, now HttpContext.Current.User is not null.

But HttpContext.Current.Profile is null and I can't find a work around.

If I set `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` it fixed the problem, But I don't want to use it because of performance issues.

**What is the equivalent Model to FormsAuthentication for Profile in `<models>`?**

**Is there a way to get the profile without using runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests?**

Web.Config:

```
 <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ASP.NET MVC" />
  <add name="ASP.NET MVC" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" />

  <remove name="MvcHttpHandler" />
  <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />


</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules>
  <remove name="WindowsAuthentication" />
  <remove name="PassportAuthentication" />

  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  <remove name="Session" />
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
  <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />

</modules>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the models list:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dh535.aspx

and  ended up removing and adding all the modules I use.

Please let me know if you know a better way to get profile and Roles with MVC Routing on IIS 7.

```
 <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
      <remove name="Session" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="Profile" />
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
      <remove name="OutputCache" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <add name="Profile" type="System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule" />
      <add name="RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule" />
      <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule" />
```